# Having trouble displaying axios data properly in nodeJS, puts data in one tag instead of giving each its own element

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, pug

So I'm practicing Node JS after taking a udemy course I'm using Pug as a template engine. In the video we made cards and each had its own card for each piece of data passed. My code looks close to the videos (sense I'm not doing the same exact thing) but it puts all the data from my axios request into one element instead of giving the data its own element. If anyone can point me in the right direction I'd love it thanks.

Controller file

```
exports.getAllSymbols = async (req, res, next) => {
  let data = [];
  const x = await axios.get(options.allStocksURL, options.allStockOptions);

  const stocks = await x.data.data[0];
  const stock = x.data.data[0].name;
  const symbol = stocks.symbol.toString();

  for (let y = 0; y <= x.data.data.length - 1; y++) {
    data.push(x.data.data[y].symbol);
  }

  res.status(200).render("base", {
    StockName: stock,
    StockSym: data,
  });
};
```

Pug File

```
html
    head
        meta(charset='UTF-8')
        meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width', initial-scale='1.0')
        
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/style.css')
        link(rel='shortcut icon', type='image/png', href='/img/favicon.png')
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,700')
        title Dashboard | #{title}

    body


        // header 
        include _header



        //- CONTENT
        block content
            
        
        div
            h3 #{StockName}
            h3 (#{StockSym})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `StockName` is a string, but `StockSym` is an array. What you need is something like:

```
div
  h3=StockName
  each symbol in StockSym
    h4 #{symbol}
```

Am assuming `StockSym` is an array of a basic type, like a string.

Note that the variables `stocks` and `symbol` in your server code are never used. Do you need them?